# how to Combine between playfab and photon friend's info

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, photon, playfab

I am using pun 2 and playfab. I did that every time you add a new friend it adds him to a playfab list, this is good because I can add a friend in any time, not like pun 2 but I can't see if friends are online and get the friends room name(photon option). the problem is that I convert from playfab to photon. is there a way to do it?
here is my playfab code

```
    private void DisplayPlayfabFriends(List<PlayFab.ClientModels.FriendInfo> friendCache)
    {
        foreach (PlayFab.ClientModels.FriendInfo f in friendCache)
        {
            bool isfound = false;
            if(myfriends != null)
            {
                foreach (PlayFab.ClientModels.FriendInfo g in myfriends)
                {
                    if (f.FriendPlayFabId == g.FriendPlayFabId)
                    {
                        isfound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isfound == false)
            {
                UIFriend listing = Instantiate(uiPrefab, container);
                if(listing != null)
                {
                    listing.Initialize(f);
                    listing.friendNameText.text = f.TitleDisplayName;

                }
            }
        }
        myfriends = friendCache;
    }
```

here is the photon code

```
    public void Initialize(Photon.Realtime.FriendInfo friendInfo)
    {
        info = friendInfo;
        roomName = $"{infophoton.UserId}";
        friendNameText.text = $"{info.UserId}";

        if (infophoton.IsOnline)
        {
            onlineImage.color = onlineColor;
        }
        else
        {
            onlineImage.color = offlineColor;
        }
    }
```

how to Combine between them both?

Answer (score 0):

I replied on the official Photon forum [here](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/52542/#Comment_52542).
Quoting my reply:

> Assuming you use the PlayFab integration with Photon as we recommend
> it, Photon UserID and PlayFab ID will be the same. So you can cache
> friends in a dictionary with keys set to their FriendID which is the
> Photon UserID / PlayFab ID and as values create a new class that
> combines info from PlayFab's FriendInfo and Photon's FriendInfo. Then
> periodically call PlayFab's GetFriends, inside its callback update the
> cached list of friends AND call Photon's FindFriends (when applicable
> / outside of rooms). In the callback of FindFriends update the cached
> friends' list and update the UI.